# Extract all possible errors in a function not just the first one

Tags: r, function, error-handling

In my function below, input element `"a"` throws an error (as it should). I can catch that first error silently using `try()`.

But, I was wondering if it might be possible to catch ALL other input values that produce an error (in the example below `"b"` will also produce an error)?

```
foo <- function(x){
  
  lapply(x, function(i) i+1)
}

# EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo(list(1, "a", "b", 2))

try(foo(list(1, "a", "b", 2)), silent = T)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `tryCatch` to handle error condition and return `NA` for error values and use the `NA` values to identify erroneous input.

```
foo <- function(x){
  lapply(x, function(i) tryCatch(i+1, error = function(e) NA))
}

val <- list(1, "a", "b", 2)
result <- foo(val)
error_input <- val[is.na(result)]

result
#[[1]]
#[1] 2

#[[2]]
#[1] NA

#[[3]]
#[1] NA

#[[4]]
#[1] 3

error_input
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also convert to `numeric` which automatically changes the non-numeric elements to `NA`

```
foo <- function(x) suppressWarnings(lapply(x, function(i) as.numeric(i) + 1))
foo(list(1, "a", "b", 2))
```